# Multiple plurals of the word "die"

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number

I see that the [Oxford dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/die_2) has a plural *dice* for "a small cube with a different number of spots on each of its sides, used in games of chance". However, there is no plural listed for "a block with a special shape that is used for shaping pieces of metal" (both definitions summarized).

[Researchgate](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Two-dies-arranged-side-by-side-in-a-wirebonded-QFN-package_fig10_311926962) has a photograph of "Two dies arranged side-by-side".

Is *dies* the correct plural of this meaning of *die*? Why do the two meanings have different plurals? Which was in use first?

Comment: You have two words here that look and sound the same. Not the same word with two meanings. I *can* and tin *can*, too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Singular of "dice".](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/167104/singular-of-dice) Also [Why do some people pedantically cling to dying word forms (e.g. die, oxen)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/243/) and [More dice and die confusion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/267065/)

Comment: The claimed duplicates neither directly query nor answer about the use of 'dies' not 'dice' as the plural of the 'tap and die' sense of 'die'.

Comment: Why do we use *flied* for baseballs and *flew* for birds? Why do we used *hanged* for people and *hung* for things? Why do we use *leaves* for those things that fall off trees and *Leafs* for hockey players? Why do we use *foci* for the points in ellipses and *focuses* for topics under discussion? Because language is irregular.

Comment: @PeterShor - language is irregular for a number of reasons. Trying to understand when and where irregularities appeared is part of our job, I think.

Comment: @user66974 The most common reason is that irregular forms are historic traditions. When new formations are created, we usually adopt regular forms for them. I'll bet the "tool and die" sense is much newer than the "throwing dice" form.

Comment: @Barmar - that what I’ve been trying to say, but there are users who just reply   “that’s English, darling” and are happy with that.

Comment: It seems like this discussion is getting kind of dicey.

Comment: There are [several words with multiple alternative plurals](https://www.merriam-webster.com/grammar/tricky-plural-words-explained). Sometimes a particular form is preferred in a particular context as with indices vs indexes. The explanation is basically the linguistic equivalent of Brownian motion, which may or may not be interesting to different people.

Answer (score -3):

They are not 'multiple plurals of the word "die",' nor anything like that, any more than either of those nouns has to do with the verb 'die' as in 'cease to live'.

How sure are you that Oxford actually has a plural 'dice' for 'a small cube…' rather than 'small cubes'?

Which other dictionaries listed no plural for 'a block… used to shape things'?

FYI the small cubes are so commonly pluralised as 'dice' that many, if not most native speakers think there is no separate singular term. That one cube is 'a dice.'

Quite separately plural shaping blocks are, 'dies' and the differences between the nouns - and the verb - prolly stem from which has French, German or Latin origins.

Comment: -1: This answer shows no research whatsoever. They all have [the same origin](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/die#Noun), from the French word *de* (*dé* in modern French). And the word for "block used to cast things" originated in English from the word for "gambling cube".

Comment: PeterShor Thank you so much, and how could that matter here? Do you reallydoubt  that whatever their roots or routes, they are not 'multiple plurals of the word "die",' nor anything like that, any more than either of those nouns has to do with the verb 'die' as in 'cease to live'?

Comment: What I'm doubting is that the difference between the nouns "prolly stem from which has French, German, or Latin origins". Both nouns derive from the same French word.

Comment: PeterShor How could those doubts matter, in the context of the Question?

I tried to make that Answer as general as I could, suggesting some vague difference among routes from French, German or Latin roots. I think that view both valid and so vague it's not worthy of challenge.

If you want 'routes' instead of 'roots,' just say the word!

If you'd like to explain in detail the route by which both nouns derive from the same French word yet arrive at different meanings in modern English, please do.

If you'd like to explain how either noun differs from the modern English verb, please do.